# Typescript : Using number as key in map

Tags: typescript

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315131/enforcing-the-type-of-the-indexed-members-of-a-typescript-object) suggests it's valid to declare a map which enforces a `number` as a key.

However, when I try the following in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20Foo%0A%7B%0A%09stringMap%3A%20%7B%20%5Bs%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09numberMap%3A%20%7B%20%5Bs%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%7D), I get an error.

```
class Foo
{
    stringMap: { [s: string]: string; } = {};
    numberMap: { [s: number]: string; } = {};
}
```

`numberMap` generates the following compiler error:

> Cannot convert `'{}'` to `'{ [s: number]: string; }'`: Index signatures of
>   types `'{}'` and `'{ [s: number]: string; }'` are incompatible `{}`

What's the correct way to declare this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is a bug or not (I'd need to check the spec), but it's definitely OK to do this as a workaround:

```
class Foo
{
    stringMap: { [s: string]: string; } = {};
    numberMap: { [s: number]: string; } = <any>{};
}
```

If something's indexable by number you'd usually use `[]` instead of `{}`, but that's obviously up to you.