# What do square brackets mean in a type definition in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36966444/1804173), I have seen a union type definition wrapped into square brackets (**edit**: the question has been fixed by now). So far, I've only seen union types without square brackets. What is the difference between e.g.:

```
type UnionA = number | string;
type UnionB = [number | string];
```

I'm aware of the following meaning of square brackets in TS:

- Array types `T[]`
- Object index structrues ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38404400/1804173))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've missed a basic type of TypeScript: [Tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html).

So the semantics of `UnionA` and `UnionB` are different:

```
let x: UnionA = 0      // works
let x: UnionA = ""     // works
let x: UnionB = 0      // doesn't work
let x: UnionB = ""     // doesn't work
let x: UnionB = [0]    // works
let x: UnionB = [""]   // works
```

Basically `UnionB` is a tuple of length 1 with its first element being a union of `number | string`.

In retrospect, the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36966444/1804173) most likely

- didn't mean to use `[]` to get the plain union type, or
- was intended to use `,` instead of `|` to get a meaningful tuple with multiple fields.