# typescript what does square brackets mean in interface?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I see the following code in vue [github link](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/reactivity/src/ref.ts)

```js
declare const RefSymbol: unique symbol
export declare const RawSymbol: unique symbol

export interface Ref<T = any> {
  value: T
  
  [RefSymbol]: true
}
```

what is RefSymbol mean here? i have tried this code:

```
let test:Ref={value:1}
```

vscode tell me that I am missing attributes of `[RefSymbol]`

i had read these questions:

1. [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404400/what-do-square-brackets-mean-where-a-field-should-be-in-typescript)
2. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

some example code is

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string;
}
 
let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
 
let myStr: string = myArray[0];
```

which is quite different with the first example code , it use`:true` rather than type `:string` , and i did not know how to pass value to [RefSymbol] ,can anyone explain this thing? thanks for any reply

Comment: Perfectly explained here already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404400/what-do-square-brackets-mean-where-a-field-should-be-in-typescript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do square brackets mean where a field should be in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404400/what-do-square-brackets-mean-where-a-field-should-be-in-typescript)

Comment: It's possible to use `let test:Ref={value:1, [RefSymbol]: true}`. That also means that `test[RefSymbol]` will be true when you run it. (assuming it has been defined somewhere, e.g. `const RefSymbol = Symbol("key");`)

Answer (score 2):

oh it's a javascript declaration where `RefSymbol` is a constant.
It's like this.

```js
const key = "size"

const map = {
  [key]: 0
}

console.log(map[key]) // 0
```

typesccript declare also `RefSymbol` is declared as `unique symbol` which means it is a unique and invariant symbol set as key

Comment: why i  need to use `let test:Ref={value:1,[RefSymbol]:true}`  when i create an instance of `Ref`? i think `RefSymbol` is already assign const `true`, i dont need to add it again, just like a function `void func(int a,int b=0)`,i can call `func(1)` and i dont need assign `b` because b has default value `0`

Comment: You can not! Symbol is a special data type it cannot be recreated `Symbol("a") !== Symbol("a")` if you want to do so you must have access to the RefSymbol declared in the import and it