# I can't understand the data structure represented by the typescript type declaration

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
type DocumentData = { [field: string]: any };
let data1: DocumentData = {4:3};

console.log(data1); //{4:3}
```

key is string type,
value is any type,
Doesn't it mean that the DocumentData type in the above code is the object type of the above type?
I know Dart, so isn't it the Map<String, dynamic> type in Dart?

However, when I ran the above code on the site below, it seems that no error occurred. Am I misunderstanding something?
https://playcode.io/1081552

As indicated above.As explained above, I can't grasp what kind of data structure the DocumentData type indicates.

Comment: Why not use a JS `Map`?

Comment: What is causing the confusion here? That number keys are allowed?

Comment: It is by design. Indexing by a number is a subset of indexing by a string, so indexing by a number when a string would have been valid is also valid (Source: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7660#issuecomment-200543029)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this: [What do square brackets mean where a field should be in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404400/what-do-square-brackets-mean-where-a-field-should-be-in-typescript)

TL:DR `DocumentData` is an object with an indexable field.

So when you instantiate `data1` with `4` as the key, `4` is a valid index.

Comment: You tried passing a number where string is expected? See [fixed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gYwK4FsIDtgwIbGwHgBUA+KAXigG8oBtAawhAC4oBnYAJwEt0BzAXRaEoAXwDcAWABQCOOnZQAJrmwBGFvGRpMOPPmzoQpCtQAsTAMyjJMuQuV4ATBsSoMWFfnbc+xqlHMAIgtA62kgA)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I felt strongly that I needed to learn the basics of TypeScript.