# Strange Typescript Return Types

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Not my proudest moment, but for the life of me, I can't understand what the return type is for this example code.

```
myFunctionName(myParameter: string): {[key: string]: any} {
    // Some code
}
```

I've tried searching, but I don't really have the "language" to search for it properly.

I understand the meaning of the "any" keyword, and I think I understand that in the square brackets a property is being defined of type string. But that's the best I've got. What's happening here?

Comment: Its just a Javascript object as return type

Comment: Out of curiosity I pasted that code into [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and it's flagged as not valid. `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' or 'any' must return a value`. Where did you spot that code?

Comment: Hi Jason, that seems like a sensible error message to me. The "// Some code" comment is in place of some code that should return a value. Because in my example I hid that detail, this code would not compile correctly, as the function needs to return a value but currently doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an object (or a map in other languages) with a string key and any kind of value.

Comment: I think I can guess that from the context of the example function. How would you use/create an object like this in the function?

For example, given an object of type "{[key: string]: any}" called myMap, how would I get a property of it? myMap['example'] or myMap.key['example']?

Comment: `return `{example: 'someValue'}` and `myMap.example` or `myMap['example']`

Comment: OK awesome. Last question, promise! Does that mean that "key" in this instance is a keyword of typescript?

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter what name is used (`key` or somthing else). See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/39801356/217408 (where `s` is used), https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7029 (where `x` is used). I haven't found anything about what meaning the index name has.

Comment: Alright, no worries. Unless a stunningly descriptive answer is put up in the next hour I'll mark this as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here the parameter in the function signature should be a 'string' and the return type of function should be an object with keys as string and any type of values. For e.g.

```
return {
  'a' : {},
  'b' : 'string',
  'c' : 2,
  'd' : false,
}
```