# typescript type for object with unknown keys, but only numeric values?

Tags: typescript, object, types

I have an object that I get from an external source at runtime. It has arbitrary string string valued keys, but only numric values. It could look like:

```
{foo:1, bar:3}
```

but it might as well look like

```
{asdf: 1}
```

I want the typescript compiler to know that *for all present keys, the value is numeric*. I tried things like `type numObj = {string: number}` and `type numObj = {[string]: number}` but neither works.

What is the suiting type declaration?

Comment: `{ [key: string]: number }`? Read the docs on indexable types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: that sure works. thanks. :) write it as an answer and ill accept it. I read the docs about indexable types under 'advanced types' and did not understand it. thanks for the reference to more adequate section on indexable types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enforcing the type of the indexed members of a Typescript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315131/enforcing-the-type-of-the-indexed-members-of-a-typescript-object)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As given by jonrsharpe in his comment [typescript type for object with unknown keys, but only numeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847561/typescript-type-for-object-with-unknown-keys-but-only-numeric-values#comment82659205_47847561):

> { [key: string]: number }? Read the docs on indexable types:
>   [www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

Answer (score 12):

[Typescript's `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) could also be used for this.

```
type CustomType = Record<string, number>
```