# How to convert to interface an object without knowing keys?

Tags: json, typescript

I want to convert a json into a typescript object. Example of the json:

```json
{
  "key1": {
    "a": "b"
  },
  "key2": {
    "a": "c"
  }
}
```

The key `key1` & `key2` are not known. So, I can't just directly put them as interface. The object associated with their key are always the same.

Actually, I made the object like:

```js
export interface MyObj {
  a: string;
}
```

But how can I do to make the json converted into an object ?

I tried to directly made a map as object type like:

```js
export interface AllMyObj {
  valKey: Map<string, MyObj>;
}
```

But I don't know what to set instead of `valKey`.

Comment: `Record<string, MyObj>` or `{ [key: string]: MyObj }` ?

Comment: @VLAZ Maybe, I don't know what are they, and which one is better than the other

Comment: [Enforcing the type of the indexed members of a Typescript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13315131) | [typescript type for object with unknown keys, but only numeric values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47847561) | [How to declare a typed object with arbitrary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36590284) | [What type to use for a dictionary-like object in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57336063)

Comment: The first and second question seems off-topic according to my own. The last can be a duplicate, but with an answer that doesn't seems so good. Also, I didn't know what to search before posting, so I didn't found good post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface should extend `Record<string, MyObj>` ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8B5AIwCs4BvAWACg45MAuOAZximQHMBuegL716yVBhx4AggBtpRMpVCokAEzZwASsGzQVAHg5ck3ADQESFAHxUhdejqQc4ECqxlyLlALzV6jAEQA1sCEAIz%20rLQMjHD%20mBGxpP5%20cAImKUEhAEwJUTGx8az%202MnRtgJAA)):

```
export interface MyObj {
  a: string;
}

interface AllMyObj extends Record<string, MyObj>{}
```

Or just use it as a type ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgWQE8B5AIwCs4BvAWACg45MAuOAZximQHMBuegL716MQmDwBBADZSiZSgF44AJWDZoAEwA8HLkm4AaAiQoA%20YXXVIOcCBVbTZJxdXqMARAGtghAIzvWWgZGOHdMANDSdzc4AQMYrx8AJgigkNDw1ndsaOChOgEgA)):

```
export interface MyObj {
  a: string;
}

type AllMyObj = Record<string, MyObj>
```

Comment: Generics save the world

Comment: Why should the interface extend it? To me it makes more sense to just be `type AllMyObj = Record<string, MyObj>`. Or not even giving it a name at all and using `Record<string, MyObj>` directly.

Comment: I've the question to literally (he wanted an interface). Using it as a type (with or without naming) is fine as well. Updated the answer.