# Typescript: allow a generic type to only be an object with 'string' properties

Tags: typescript

I am wondering if it is possible in TS to enforce the type of the properties for a generic. I would like to only allow passing a generic of an object type with 'string' properties. Raise an error if for instance the passed generic interface would contain number or symbols properties.

Here is a [POC](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Test%3CT%20extends%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%7D%3E%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20data%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getValue%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(key%3A%20K)%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.data%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20the%20property%20is%20a%20string%20%3D%20ok%0D%0Aconst%20okay%20%3D%20new%20Test%3C%7B%20%22aString%22%3A%20string%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20the%20property%20is%20a%20number%20%3D%20should%20raise%20an%20error%0D%0Aconst%20shouldFail%20%3D%20new%20Test%3C%7B%200%3A%20string%20%7D%3E()%3B%0D%0A) of what I tried and commented the behaviour I am looking for:

```
class Test<T extends {[key: string]: any}>{
    private data: T;

    public getValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
        return this.data[key];
     }
}

// the property is a string = ok
const okay = new Test<{ "aString": string }>();

// the property is a number = should raise an error
const shouldFail = new Test<{ 0: string }>();
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315131/enforcing-the-type-of-the-indexed-members-of-a-typescript-object

Comment: @bugs it's a different case, 11315131 does not cover extending another interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the object has a string index we can index the object by number as well, so there is no reason for the compiler to throw an error number keys. This is by design.

```
declare let skeys: { [key: string]: number }
let v1 = skeys[0] // number 
let v2 = skeys["0"] // number

declare let nkeys: { [key: number]: number }
let v3 = nkeys[0] // number 
let v4 = nkeys["0"] // error 


declare let snkeys: {
    [key: number]: number;
    [key: string]: string | number // The string index has to contain any value reuned by the number index
}
let v5 = snkeys[0] // number 
let v6 = snkeys["0"] // string| number
```

We can use a conditional type to force an error if the object contains any non-string keys. The error will not be very pretty, but it is readable and can get the job done:

```
class Test<T extends { [key: string]: any } & (keyof T extends string ? {} : "T must obnly have string keys") >{
    private data!: T;

    public getValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
        return this.data[key];
    }
}

// the property is a string = ok
const okay = new Test<{ "aString": string }>();
// Error: Type '{ 0: string; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: any; } & "T must only have string keys"'.
const shouldFail = new Test<{ 0: string }>();
```

**Note**

If you don't have any other constraints on the values of `T` a simple `object` type would work as well

```
class Test<T extends object & (keyof T extends string ? {} : "T must only have string keys") >{ }
```

Comment: +1 I would even suggest : `class Test<T extends object & (keyof T extends string ? {} : "T must only have string keys") >{
`

Comment: @FlavienVolken Yeah, that would work too.. the index signature would help constraining the values of the object

Comment: @FlavienVolken added your suggestion :)