# Index signature for iteration in typescript

Tags: typescript, index-signature

We can all see that this code is valid javascript:

```
const myObj = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: 123,
  baz: "important stuff"
};

['foo', 'bar'].forEach((key) => {
  delete myObj[key];
});
```

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ foo: string; bar: number; baz: string; }'.

So what's the best way of doing this TypeScript compatible?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeBYAKBhgDMQQAuGAImgCcBLMAc2oBpDiUBDOqgRgBMAZg5EYPAF5VqDOAAcQdKNzCxoAVxIlqhAL4BuQoQAUAbQDkZEBbYwLPOhYC6ASgB0ZOgFFuwABYmJgDWAKYIrlgAfLicMAAmoQA2oVCh8MjoZmEIzkYEeq75QA

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/13315131/990642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing your array :

```
const myObj = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: 123,
  baz: "important stuff"
};

const myArray: (keyof typeof myObj)[] = ['foo', 'bar']

myArray.forEach(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is:

```
(['foo', 'bar'] as (keyof typeof myObj)[]).forEach((key) => {
  delete myObj[key];
});
```

But it does not prevent typing errors in the array-strings.