# Preserve Type when using Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm fairly new to TypeScript, so I'm in the process of upgrading my old projects to utilize it.

However, I'm not sure how to preserve the correct Type when calling Object.entries on some data.

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-gould-telcz?file=/src/App.tsx)

As an example:

**Level.tsx:**

```
  const UnpassableTileComponents = useMemo(() => 
    Object.entries(levelData[`level_${gameLevel}`].tiles.unpassable_tiles).map(([tileType, tiles]) => (
      tiles.map(([leftPos, topPos], index) => (
        <UnpassableTile
          key={`${tileType}_${index}`}
          leftPos={leftPos * 40}
          topPos={topPos * 40}
          tileType={tileType}
        />
      ))
    )
  ).flat(), [gameLevel])
```

**levelData.tsx:**

```
import levelJSON from "./levelJSON.json";

interface ILevelJSON {
  [key: string]: Level;
}

interface Level {
  tiles: Tiles;
}

interface Tiles {
  unpassable_tiles: UnpassableTiles;
}

interface UnpassableTiles {
  rock: Array<number[]>;
  tree: Array<number[]>;
}

export default levelJSON as ILevelJSON;
```

**levelJSON.json:**

```
{
  "level_1": {
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": {
        "rock": [[0, 0]],
        "tree": [[2, 0]]
      }
    }
  },
  "level_2": {
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": {
        "rock": [[]],
        "tree": [[]]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the case of the above, tiles represents an Array of arrays, each with two numbers.
Therefore, [leftPos, topPos] should both be typed as number. However, in Level.tsx, they have properties of any. I could get my desired result with the following:

```
  const UnpassableTileComponents = useMemo(() => 
    Object.entries(levelData[`level_${gameLevel}`].tiles.unpassable_tiles).map(([tileType, tiles]) => (
      tiles.map(([leftPos, topPos] : number[], index: number) => (
        <UnpassableTile
          key={`${tileType}_${index}`}
          leftPos={leftPos * 40}
          topPos={topPos * 40}
          tileType={tileType}
        />
      ))
```

But shouldn't number[] be inferred anyways?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider modifying the above code to constitute a [mcve] as mentioned in [ask].  Ideally something that could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and allow people who want to help to demonstrate your issue for themselves.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Added as requested :)

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/70420283/990642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jcalz's excellent answer explains why what you are trying to do is so tricky. His approach could work if you want to keep your underlying schemas and JSON the same. But I will point out that you can sidestep the entire problem just by structuring your data differently. I think that will make your developer experience, as well as the clarify of *what your data is*, better.

One of the fundamental problems you're having is that you're trying to treat a map of `key: value` pairs as, in your case, some sort of list of impassable tiles. But it is inherently unwieldy and confusing to work with `Object.entries` just to get at your impassable tile types.

Why not define `ImpassableTile` as a type, and the list of impassable tiles as an array of that type? That better matches, conceptually, what the data actually represents. It also sidesteps `Object.entries` and its difficulties entirely, and makes iterating over the data more simple and clear.

```
// levelData.ts
import levelJSON from "./levelJSON.json";

interface ILevelJSON {
  [key: string]: Level;
}

interface Level {
  tiles: Tiles;
}

export type UnpassableType = "rock" | "tree";

type UnpassableTile = {
  type: UnpassableType;
  position: number[];
};

interface Tiles {
  unpassable_tiles: UnpassableTile[];
}

export default levelJSON as ILevelJSON;
```

To properly match the new interface, you'd need to modify levelJSON.json as well. But note that it's a lot cleaner and you'd don't need to define empty arrays for rocks or trees in level_2, those are simply absent:

```
{
  "level_1": {
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": [
        { "type": "rock", "position": [0, 0] },
        { "type": "rock", "position": [2, 0] },
        { "type": "tree", "position": [2, 2] }
      ]
    }
  },
  "level_2": {
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": []
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can very easily map over your impassable tiles, their types, and associated position data, all while retaining full type inference and safety. And it looks a lot more clear and understandable IMO.

```
// App.tsx
const UnpassableTileComponents = React.useMemo(() => {
  return levelData[`level_1`].tiles.unpassable_tiles.map(
    ({ type, position: [leftPos, topPos] }) => (
      <UnpassableTile
        key={`level_1_${type}_${leftPos}_${topPos}`}
        leftPos={leftPos}
        topPos={topPos}
        tileType={type}
      />
    )
  );
}, []);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-snyder-u9x60?file=/src/App.tsx

---

You can further extend this philosophy to how you structure your Levels and their interfaces. Why not have `levelJSON` be an array of `Level` objects, each with a name and set of tiles?

```
interface Tiles {
  unpassable_tiles: UnpassableTile[];
}

interface Level {
  name: string;
  tiles: Tiles;
}

export type UnpassableType = "rock" | "tree";

type UnpassableTile = {
  type: UnpassableType;
  position: number[];
};
```

Your corresponding data would look a lot cleaner:

```
[
  {
    "name": "level_1",
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": [
        { "type": "rock", "position": [0, 0] },
        { "type": "rock", "position": [2, 0] },
        { "type": "tree", "position": [2, 2] }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "level_2",
    "tiles": {
      "unpassable_tiles": []
    }
  }
]
```

And iterating over it would become even more clear:

```
const level = levelData[0];

const UnpassableTileComponents = React.useMemo(() => {
  return level.tiles.unpassable_tiles.map(
    ({ type, position: [leftPos, topPos] }) => (
      <UnpassableTile
        key={`${level.name}_${type}_${leftPos}_${topPos}`}
        leftPos={leftPos}
        topPos={topPos}
        tileType={type}
      />
    )
  );
}, [level]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-grass-dnohi?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: This part was exactly what I needed: `[key: string]: Level;`. This allows `Object.entries` and `for (key in obj) {` to preserve typing.

Answer (score 13):

This is related to questions like [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55012174/2887218).   The answer to both is that object types in TypeScript are not *exact* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)); values of object types are allowed to extra properties not known about by the compiler.  This allows interface and class inheritance, which is very useful.  But it can lead to confusion.

For example, if I have a value `nameHaver` of type `{name: string}`, I know it has a `name` property, but I don't know that it *only* has a `name` property.  So I can't say that `Object.entries(nameHaver)` will be `Array<["name", string]>`:

```
interface NameHaver { name: string }
declare const nameHaver: NameHaver;
const entries: Array<["name", string]> = Object.entries(nameHaver); // error here: why?
entries.map(([k, v]) => v.toUpperCase());
```

What if `nameHaver` has more than just a `name` property, as in:

```
interface NameHaver { name: string }
class Person implements NameHaver { constructor(public name: string, public age: number) { } }
const nameHaver: NameHaver = new Person("Alice", 35);
const entries: Array<["name", string]> = Object.entries(nameHaver); // error here: ohhh
entries.map(([k, v]) => v.toUpperCase());  // explodes at runtime!
```

Oops.  We assumed that `nameHaver`'s values were always `string`, but one is a `number`, which will not be happy with `toUpperCase()`.  The only safe thing to assume that `Object.entries()` produces is `Array<[string, unknown]>` (although the standard library uses `Array<[string, any]>` instead).

---

So what can we do?  Well, if you happen to know and are absolutely sure that a value has only the keys known about by the compiler, then you can write your own typing for `Object.entries()` and use that instead... and you need to be very careful with it.  Here's one possible typing:

```
type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
function ObjectEntries<T extends object>(t: T): Entries<T>[] {
  return Object.entries(t) as any;
}
```

The `as any` is a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that suppresses the normal complaint about `Object.entries()`.  The type `Entries<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) that we immediately [look up](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) to produce a union of the known entries:

```
const entries = ObjectEntries(nameHaver);
// const entries: ["name", string][]
```

That is the same type I manually wrote before for `entries`.  If you use `ObjectEntries` instead of `Object.entries` in your code, it should "fix" your issue.  But do keep in mind you are relying on the fact that the object whose entries you are iterating has no unknown extra properties.  If it ever becomes the case that someone adds an extra property of a non-`number[]` type to `unpassable_tiles`, you might have a problem at runtime.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHJwLYQBJwG7TIDeyImEAXMgM5hSgDmyAvgFAIA2c11yACtGoB7EMmAYADhwhZwvdFlwEoxZAhG0oAVwRghUABQStAIw7AEpclU2MANMmNmLyOA0qktGE9ACUq5hZ2DTArRXxoKgUcCJUAXlIIAHd+QREDACIAQXMkDIcAZgBWXwBuYJBaZAhweghqKiyoKDgATwAeAG0Msix8mjpGAF0APmQEgHkTACsIXQA6GsH6g16Y5TLkAHot6ub9ZAALaA8hQ-PWJbrqeYw4CQMDToBrBzwh-zixvHm9AFUJBJoABhbgQAy+TbbXYQAAeUiEABN6q5QtpwOIIABCVgVYTSeYcIQMAxTWYLK7AFZrJR+Mq4sCtIHIACitSp1HaABUxgkSJ0ANJiUTPCCtIQwZBcoZUQUOLmCoZDFgvMUSqVDcowLQgXTAETIMlzMBs5acrnVWGQECI3hCGbGkYGMBULm+Kim67ckadZVEVjIQPIKAQMBaKCiI0U9krMD+biuECtcpsPGhSn1ABM40NDt0no5q3ItKg9J2ahC1Rj1Ezsp65H6thADCGvsu1czt3ujxebw+42+vyEAKBUFB1HBkNKgfLiKEKLAh2AvDhCORAH5caxy7Q4Da4FBEchzCYWlBWqxQJBYIgUFGwMCQtpdAd-UGq2bvQYhFR+Q0BvQzYylKLDIAAPsgTQtK0AAywCit67rIJ0TYMPKraagGQYZtQ36-swSEoYMzYOHurQYSmrBAA)

Comment: I was in the process of writing something similar but yours is more comprehensive. I was also going to mention that you could add `[key: string]: Array<number[]>;` to the `UnpassableTiles` interface. He would lose strict enforcement of the keys of that interface limiting it to "rock" or "tree", but depending on his use case that might not matter.