# typescript: how to correctly type key and value parameters in Object.entries().forEach([key,value]) =>

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I got an object with specific key/value parameters and I want to iterate over it with entries() method of Object followed by a forEach() method of Array. However I do not understand how I have to type this configuration to avoiding a typescript error:

```
type objType = {
  prop1: number | undefined;
  prop2: number | undefined;
  prop3: number | undefined;
};

const obj: objType = {
  prop1: 2,
  prop2: 0,
  prop3: undefined,
};

//1st attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
});

//2nd attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([key, value]: [keyof objType, number | undefined]) => {
    if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
  }
);
```

In first attempt, I let typescript infer the type of `key` (→ `string`) and `value` (→ `number|undefined`). But in this case I got an error when doing `obj[key]` :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'objType'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'objType'.

In second attempt I forced the type of `key` to correspond to the key of `obj` using `keyof` operator, but this type definition is not allowed and I got the following message :

> Argument of type '([key, value]: [keyof objType, number | undefined]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: [string, number | undefined], index: number, array: [string, number | undefined][]) => void'. Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type '[string, number | undefined]' is not assignable to type '[keyof objType, number | undefined]'.
> Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof objType'.

I understand the failure for first attempt but not for the second. Why TS believes that I want to assign string to the string enumeration, I'm guessing to do the opposite...?

How is the correct way to type this configuration ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Why

First of all we need to understand why this happening:
Let's check the simplest example:

```
const obj = {a: 1};
Object.keys(obj).forEach((key:keyof typeof obj)=> ''); // fails because Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a"'
```

This happens, because TS can't guarantee that there is no other keys in the object. Thus, it can't guarantee that key will be **ONLY** 'a'.

In  your case, this means that TS can't ensure that value of `obj[key]` will be number. It might be anything, thus TS throws an error.

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKYDFzXmACgEMAnAcwC5EBvIq5KEmMMgGkQCN7HmyBfAJTUAUIkQB6cYgAqACxjJECxBhhRZGEoigBPAA4YAJogAGDJiwDaAXROI4WgLSIA7mtnaNiWUQgBrKgIAIiIggB8gjiCBGwA6RFEJKQAhECgldLQYMll0nwA3DHt1TUQ-DB1FIkUXDAAbOoBCRIgEBjKKxQBeRAB5DgArDGhY8sricgEAbmE%20YWFJRDA4F0Q6jCgAckU0InLPIurkEDQ9WAREYCIYOop51rB2tB0AQXITjDB0npExOkQgqhMEFWIkuAD1LwQS0qEFwBgAB4GaBGIKzeaLZbpEprOBwPSuG51RC%20KAgIgNHQZTREKBFOCFLTBUIRKIRCDRGwLKQcNIHby%20crGXQGVxwEB1YxYkkQVrgdLAByeWnCIHYXDnQjPN5kD5faZAA)

### Option #1

One way to handle this is to force TS to use your types:

```
//1st attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key as keyof typeof obj] = 5;
});

//2nd attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([key, value]) => {
    if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key as keyof typeof obj] = 5;
  }
);
```

This is OK in case you are absolute sure that no extra keys will be present.

### Option #2

Another way is to redesign your types into something a bit more generic:

```
type objType = {
    prop1: number | undefined;
    prop2: number | undefined;
    prop3: number | undefined;
}

const obj: Record<string, number | undefined> = {
    prop1: 2,
    prop2: 0,
    prop3: undefined,
};

//1st attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
});

//2nd attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value]) => {
        if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
    }
);
```

At the code above we are clearly states that we allows any string keys.

Please [check](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) for some extra details

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick and detailled answer.
I didn't figured out that TS could consider the case where a key is different from keyof obj, as it comes litteraly from a map over the existing keys. But ok I can imagine a case where the callback of the foreach may modify more than the current key (even if weird)

Comment: @SebastienD To be more clear I've added an example why key is string.
Is the question answered, or you need some more help?

Comment: thanks for the new example. It's ok your answer solved my problem, thanks a lot

Comment: this fails for me because typescript wants to know the type of the value. I can't figure out where to assign the value a type.

Comment: @FiddleFreak could you provide some example? Or open the question?

Comment: @Drag13 I did here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445422/how-to-assign-type-to-key-value-in-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 3):

### Option 3: Use a key signature

On your type `objType` add a key signature like so:

```
  [key: string]: number | undefined;
```

Here is the full code example:

```
type objType = {
  [key: string]: number | undefined;
  prop1: number | undefined;
  prop2: number | undefined;
  prop3: number | undefined;
};

const obj: objType = {
  prop1: 2,
  prop2: 0,
  prop3: undefined,
};

//1st attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
});

//2nd attempt
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([key, value]: [keyof objType, number | undefined]) => {
    if (value === undefined || value < 5) obj[key] = 5;
  }
);
```

Here is a screenshot showing VSCode is recognizing the typing:

[image]