# How to specify specific type while destructuring: Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am having custom types defined like this

```
export type Extensions =
  | '.gif'
  | '.png'
  | '.jpeg'
  | '.jpg'
  | '.svg'
  | '.txt'
  | '.jpg'
  | '.csv'
  | '.zip';

export type mimeType = 'image' | 'application' | 'text';

export type FileType = {
  [key in mimeType]?: Extensions[];
};
```

When used in a function i get the following error , `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'mimeType'.` While destructuring i am giving the type as `[mimeType, Extensions[]]` but still it is throwing the above error. Can someone help me?

Here is my usage when destructuring it

```
export const getAcceptedFileTypes = (mimeTypes: FileType) => {
  const acceptedTypes: Accept = {};
  Object.entries(mimeTypes).forEach(([key, extensions]: [mimeType, Extensions[]]) => {
    if (key === 'text') {
      acceptedTypes['text/*'] = extensions;
    } else if (key === 'image') {
      extensions.forEach(
        (image) => (acceptedTypes[`image/${image.substring(1)}`] = [image])
      );
    } else {
      extensions.forEach(
        (application) =>
          (acceptedTypes[`application/${application.substring(1)}`] = [
            application,
          ])
      );
    }
  });
  return acceptedTypes;
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript: how to correctly type key and value parameters in Object.entries().forEach(\[key,value\]) =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420283/typescript-how-to-correctly-type-key-and-value-parameters-in-object-entries-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the type definition of the `Object.entries` function:

```
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

You can see that the tuple in the return type always has the first element to be `string` and it's independent on the input. You'll have to convert it to the required type:

```
(Object.entries(mimeTypes) as [mimeType, Extensions[]][]).forEach(...)
```

You'll not have to give the type again in the `forEach` callback

Comment: thanks . One more quick question, can I have the only restricted items when a mimeType is selected, say if mimeType is text i extensions should just be csv, txt

Comment: you can setup an object type that maps `mimetype -> allowed types` and use that instead of the `Extension[]`. If you need more explanation, please ask another question, since it doesn't have much to do with the current one

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76099248/restrict-key-of-object-entries-to-certain-type-typescript