# Why Object.entries not taking correct types from an object type defined with "Record<>"

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Why the type of object key is not properly picked by typescript?

```js
const k: Record<'a' | 'b', number> = { a: 5, b: 6 };

Object.entries(k).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  // key: string
  // value: number
});
```

I was expecting the types to be

```js
key: 'a' | 'b'
value: number
```

Because we are saying `Record<'a' | 'b', number>` and not `Record<string, number>`.

Also how can I fix this in a safe way with out using `any`?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gLhgJQKagE4BMA8ByAQzxgB8Y8AjPAGhjAFcBbC1DAPhgF4YBvGApAFZaFJADYYAXwDcAKFkB5CgCt0UAHSowUDAEtUEABRwAlOoBmIDAFECwABaHDAbTioAnrQBuBADb1UAF0TLg4eWRgYAHoo+A8kaD0wAHMI6Niff1QkBmZWWUkTaSA)

> There is a possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62053739/3370568). But that question is not following the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - and hence the answers are too. I felt like that thread is taking too much energy to understand because it is not generalized.