# Typescript itterate through typescript object : interface but keep typing

Tags: typescript, generics, typing

I have a method which takes an object which is a Partial I wuold like to itterate though that object using Object.entries and then based on the key I wuold like to perform some operations. The interface has keys which are string but values which are string|number|string[]|DateTime. I would like the function I pass it to to know whats being passed in from the key.

The code i currently have is

```
public partialUpdate = async (id: number, fieldsToUpdate: Partial<IClient>) => {

    type temp = Partial<Record<keyof IClient, (val : string) => void>>;
    const mapping : temp = {
        name: (val) => client.setName(val),
        website: (val) => client.setWebsite(val),
        sic_codes: (val) => client.setSicCodes(val),
        phone_number: (val) => client.setPhoneNumber(val),
    };
    Object.entries(fieldsToUpdate).forEach(([key, value]) => mapping[key](value));
    return this.clientRepository.update(id, client);
};
```

and the interface is

```
export interface IClient
{
    id: number,
    creation_date: DateTime,
    name:string,
    website:string,
    phone_number:string,
    industry:string,
    sic_codes:string[],
}
```

The problem i'm currently having is if it were all string types then no issue but because of sic_codes being a string[] it will cause a type error. Is there any way to have const mapping to know what type val is from the key?

Comment: Do you have a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gi5b1v That should show the code with the type error. I'm not sure if im expecting typescript to do what its not meant to do so please le me know if thats the case

Comment: Please [edit] the question and put the [mre] directly in as plaintext; an external link to an IDE is a good supplement, but is not a replacement for having the example self-contained in the question itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your example; why do you care that your setters return values?  Is there a reason why you need `(x: string) => string` instead of `(x: string) => void` ?

Comment: `Object.entries()` is not strongly typed enough for you to write that code without type assertions.  You could give it your own custom return type, and then you need `forEach()`'s callback to be generic, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1ydXw), if you want the compiler to help.  Does that approach work for you?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hi, @jcalz thank you that example works perfectly for me. The thing i was mainly looking for is Partial<{ [K in keyof IClient]: (val: IClient[K]) => void }> . If you would like to write an answer i will hapily accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original type

```
Record<keyof IClient, (val: string) => void>
```

uses [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype), which is implemented as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).  Let's write that out explicitly in terms of mapped types:

```
{[K in keyof IClient]: (val: string) => void}
```

So, the issue here is that the `val` type `string` is not necessarily the value type of `IClient` at each key `K` in `keyof IClient`.  And the fix is to replace `string` with `IClient[K]`, an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) which means "the value type of `IClient` at key `K`":

```
type Test = { [K in keyof IClient]: (val: IClient[K]) => void };
/* type Test = {
  id: (val: number) => void;
  creation_date: (val: Date) => void;
  name: (val: string) => void;
  company_number: (val: string) => void;
  website: (val: string) => void;
  phone_number: (val: string) => void;
  industry: (val: string) => void;
  sic_codes: (val: string[]) => void;
} */
```

Looks good.

---

If we plug that in where you had your original type, there are still errors.  `Object.entries()` isn't strongly typed enough to work for what you want in TypeScript.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62053739/2887218) for more information.  You can give it stronger typings (even though this isn't 100% safe).  Even if you do that, your `forEach()` callback needs to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the particular key type `K` you're processing.  And inside that callback you need to make sure both your `value` and your `mapping[key]` are not `undefined`, if you want to be safe:

Let me make those changes, just to show that it works as you intend:

```
// Give stronger typings to Object.entries()
type Entry<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]-?: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T];
function entries<T extends object>(obj: T) {
    return Object.entries(obj) as Entry<T>[];
}

const partialUpdate = async (id: number, fieldsToUpdate: Partial<IClient>) => {
    const client = new Client();    
    const mapping: Partial<{ [K in keyof IClient]: (val: IClient[K]) => void }> = {
        name: (val) => client.setName(val),
        company_number: (val) => client.setCompanyNumber(val),
        industry: (val) => client.setIndustry(val),
        sic_codes: (val) => client.setSicCodes(val),
    };
    const e = entries(fieldsToUpdate).forEach(<K extends keyof IClient>(
        [key, value]: [K, IClient[K] | undefined]) => value && mapping[key]?.(value));
    return null;
};
```

Hooray, no errors!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.6.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGEA2wLmQbwFgAoASGABMAuZEAVwFsAjaAGhNISgjjGAHsQAfQq8INACJj2ZEHAbjkAZzBRQAcxmd+DAA5wQATyH1m0GirUhNHAO4QmS4JAuqNW3QAtBEE4xZQrlY2ZKAUdJaGQe4cTghCCPwUEErR1gDaALoyAL4kEAAeuvxQYMgImHBKSshYOHhEZLpqAG5iyNxwFIKYhsiUNKYByAA+tHSYmADcHM3AbZAdPN0gveWdfIIiYpJiM02t7XIKaeqj45P7pHMLKIl6BsZD5spu1uf0l7OHi2ERqlFXsEPhNpsgAPTg5AMOAAaxQuEY33m7TiCSSKVOWRBX2IszoTGwCHKgksdAQYBKAAoAJQEDikMCeYBKAB0lGQAF4LtMGUyWazjihuZ9eWRGcy2fd9EY-GYoFyeVcJQK-pFFaLlfy2WjEskaiLQVrJayuDxNsJRIsRRBbMgpJBaVc8nimgSich1BAwKgKIraVyAHzIbXsij7fGE4DEr1gdAbAQgB3C5ABznB0Nm3iJ7aQCNuqMx70AOXkKbTGZNQquund0eUJbL-qFpzp6dToaFGrLNPz1zrRbjOhlhmL-mg-rblYF0secoCNYHDaHDyMY-l-tna-HgSBGinHZNW6eO8Vx-XAV7JEjHtjqBA4XV3IrIZNaoBi8Ly-vj4B-vfUCApY+5BoeqoPv8gGKgBhhXq6-ZfrGADK0boBiBqpgeoa6uhn4eko3ooQgaH6v6cQkZie4ZJkB5Uth0boqR3LkehcEkC6JCJCAKjIPopTAHAmAAKq6FaEAAEJdIqVSGCAxJUgM4zyqwyAwDgmAUEoAAq-AiWJNAAApwPxgkADwYNguBgIGB6NKQkIhoYugoJAejIIqplacghSQA+NTAdYIzPFAIwBeoWSBlS6QwrougaKcmTIDQVJtJgNBaQeXlwdo3FlBU9RlDadp1FZTocGATkuRAbnckZJmYKZABKECJFAFCmfChj8DAaAleAKkpYJragS0-CUIGgZXFxPExXF1g0K5uiKnZpAtqmqUHvlVmsgRYClgog2YDSWjaKuJ7yslG2gVt4A7d6aFnRe0CHcdDIwZdgmbZZt27T+kGGC9J04fqH1Hdd31gHdYBERRSiA9eZA5FcADyTAAFYtZDVlqCkVJqRAGnabpoliDSrIwCUACiiCeFSUWdSpqV0BANGgbNGjpJ1mSHczNLZdwYB0FAIBKux+YIxVznIJT4CAZ53kFL5mnIPw6OY8G3L4Mg6QANL9CLnXdcgWmZAAtAA-DQusqVpuuZIlOScxAXU9SbELgmM6RhSpjyZPsMB0HJFrebLOBKPLPm4MrqsYxSkUx+ldJ2QLQsi6jsdY6HuMx3SVTS7LhieYGWT7BxxDTWUfF8IJentNyMlyaminBSp+OEzptcuMgdXVw1FkFTZoF2RX5QQxqtq1BDZVkJLKBaSkhUENreugMghs9f3VmZKDNCb+AdsHqNHJIxw4IAFSOVL888ZrHDuYph2DDuh9jeGd-rOaOb6etQ32qTI2vyuO5Naj8qLqBfpQIBJIzrzheKAsKEC35kHcvYRwzhFDwLeOAgBkD35eB8LA3cmDgiIKge9H+aUwGkPfsDSixCOas3bEfJBpAcjIDPuCBGOUZpwFivFbuxle6mS1rrfWa9nZGz3mAbeFDd59TAAfHBfocga3pOKEBV12w3UhrtfaEB4bimPIQ0GX0CpQweiOJ6UADGkHIBBSIJjwZmN+vYgENjSC0NSBQ0x21dow3QjYk+ZAR4pmxmHPG6lNIdxJpAMmFMoDUwQLTUyetI5+XES7XqENIoMidoYRmglmYyOtlkgqdtziB2SGpEAEAKCMODEzFAAAyJp0JeFzXClzc2rIeYQD5lcFOwtRbECRkAA)