# Is there a way to change this typescript function so that the resultant object is typed with only the keys in the map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, intellisense

The function will return an object of type `{[key: string] : T[]}`
But I am looking to improve the type safety of this function so that in the IDE I get IntelliSense on what keys are valid in the resulting object.

I've been trying to get the keys as a const value and use that to type the object, but I can't figure out the correct syntax to get it working, nor do I know if that is even a correct approach.

```
export function groupBy<T>(array: T[], getKey: (item: T) => string) {
    const map = new Map<string, T[]>();
    array.forEach((item) => {
        const key = getKey(item);
        const group = map.get(key);
        group ? group.push(item) : map.set(key, [item]);
    });

    return Object.fromEntries(map.entries());
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk8YDw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you want `groupBy()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) not only in `T`, the element type of `array`, but also in `K`, the return type of `getKey()`.  Like this:

```
function groupBy<T, K extends string>(array: T[], getKey: (item: T) => K) {
  const map = new Map<string, T[]>();
  array.forEach((item) => {
    const key = getKey(item);
    const group = map.get(key);
    group ? group.push(item) : map.set(key, [item]);
  });

  return Object.fromEntries(map.entries()) as { [P in K]: T[] }
}
```

Here `K` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `string`, so the compiler will complain if `getKey()` returns a non-`string`. But now when you call `groupBy()`, the compiler will try to infer `K` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the particular values that `getKey()` can return.

Then the return type of `groupBy()` is `{ [P in K]: T[] }` (equivalent to `Record<K, T[]>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) instead of `{ [k: string]: T[] }`.  That means it has keys of type `K` and values of type `T[]`.  Note that I needed to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the value returned by [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is of that type, since the TypeScript compiler can't verify that (see [Preserve Type when using Object.entries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62053739/2887218) or other questions for more information).

---

Let's test it out with an example:

```
interface Foo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const foos: Foo[] = [
  { name: "Alice", age: 30 },
  { name: "Bob", age: 35 },
  { name: "Carol", age: 40 },
  { name: "Dave", age: 50 }
];

const groups = groupBy(
  foos,
  (foo) => foo.age >= 40 ? "older" : foo.name.length <= 4 ? "shortname" : "other"
);
/* const groups: {
    older: Foo[];
    shortname: Foo[];
    other: Foo[];
} */

console.log("Older: " + groups.older.map(foo => foo.name).join(", "));
// Older: Carol, Dave

console.log("Shortname: " + groups.shortname.map(foo => foo.name).join(", "))
// Shortname: Bob

groups.randomKey; // error
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that `K` is the union `"older" | "shortname" | "other"` and therefore that the returned `groups` value is of type `{older: Foo[]; shortname: Foo[]; other: Foo[]}`.  And so it lets you index into `groups.older` and `groups.shortname` but it wouldn't let you index into `groups.randomKey`, which is I think what your desired behavior is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=5.1.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwE5xABwEIE8A8AKgDSIDSiApgB5SVgAmAzok1KjGMgHwAUAhqlT9cALkSEA2gF1SySlDKUxiXjDoBbcYQCUiALzdyegN4AoRIggI2iDf0wHEYSgHdEAWQf42HLqSlpPh0AbgtEQWFcADpgOFQAUX4IAAteNU09Q0RzS0trMFsAa2UneUVlDMoNUPD8mygUdCwne0xo8t4S3Fq8poxHAH5+rGjMECY09Wq9cTbopgUu5VJJaY1pXsQAX1rw1AUQVCQAeQAjACtKaFj0DQSwdhhKJl55+ieX3h09fhYTRCSAAKiE45Gk2hkOzM2zMZk4dFQwGSlEQADE4HAcuEwPwNJRxL5OMgwpZ+PJxGAQBozpRUGFYWYCrY4nAmOIMXAofpAeEAbj8eIAEQAQQANjAIJQhaRyQTEABmAAMO2IfOcePlQuwcDOMoiFMVAFZVeqBVqAMKCOBi-Vy8QAFhV2zVln5muFABF+AA3aWyw1G51maRhJkNEaYFg8tADPC8cKspiu1SsrJGVnROWIbg8p2IYZCm0MOlCxDiTPm6Ji+jIKApRD4PMFxBCybxKDmsvCuD10tmWoAegAVFYI7GsOzsX1i3SOZiZKS8u3UJ2PeiF6G6oheyk5xuuVvtohh4O4cybZRq3BkLwhScxSXUMLEABqSNMaKz1DRNq8VkGBmmLROaOjRBccCcHepBCj8YSDoOiAPk+4hWugYqkN6frnjYl7XreQoAMopB25ovu+E5RgsJGrlWf4AdklaamBEFQfqsE6GYCGIMRpHrjqZxwpRn7CIwcAaEouAhIg3F0ugqBAA)