# TypeScript typing: Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a code like this one:

```js
class Category {
  #title: string

  constructor(
    title: string,
  ) {
    this.#title = title
  }

  get title() {
    return this.#title
  }
}

function node<T extends object>(
  parent: T,
  children: Record<string, T>,
) {
  for (const [slug, value] of Object.entries(children)) {
    Object.defineProperty(parent, slug, {
      get() {
        return value
      },
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    })
  }

  return parent
}

const categories = {
  pets: node(new Category('Pets'), {
    dishes: new Category('Pets dishes'),
  }),
  cloth: node(new Category('Cloth'), {
    accessories: new Category('Accessories'),
  }),
}

for (const [slug, category] of Object.entries(categories)) {
  // string, Category
  console.log(slug, category)

  for (const [s, c] of Object.entries(category)) {
    // string, any
    console.log(s, c)
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYBcCmBzA9gJwJ7QN4ChpoBiBASwRCQC5oIEMyA7FfQ6YNJ%20jAV2ASYAFOyLlKNOg2YoANOwCUeUdAQALMhAB0pClWgBeVXqTsAvmyIokCYxKFKCRIhhu8MTVRu26J5-Bb4AGa8TAJkXNBMaAAmSAA8ACrQSAAeyEwxMGgARgBWSAIAfCJEAA5grkwItInyRMAaIDFVtABKhZgx8TwystCJRfKO7EGY0EKc3LYA2hAgvHLQAG5gC0gAutBoQdAA8vmFCFpI1YxIEJNNLacKI877hwJacUHMSAAKGGhlSBgIWCEFSqCH680W-ScD2g1gQDmU0OcrgQ7k8q3WKiIZnq0NOvAAtn8wDkqLQGLwkDiHlM3ih3MTSao%20JSVGYFP52MjUdBgacEAE2FN6BxEKhMGQLoYETybBBaNE4kImEgAO5wUXobBCADkH1l2oUkJUMU0agu8tV6uQmsButl0BNEDNEANOLZONAaHU8tiSCVlvg1swttgIC9ald0qIYGAwAuEHF5qiAY1wZ1AEFY-HEy7DeY84ExhgJkLZuClsBU9gtjtHgVnnzzpdK0Gm3dpQB6DtSRgsfqBsXYdhCtBULRhlBCcv9FuDrDs0bjSZcYVzGc13YHevHRsS5tV%20f3Zxdnt9aBgJhYFQjscTqcz9lYgVAA)

In the second `console.log` the type of `c` is `any`.
I think this is because inside `node` functions, `Object.defineProperty` is used.
How I can write typings for this?

Comment: `Object.entries(category)` is iterating over a type `Category`,  so what type do you expect `c` to be?..

Comment: I expected a type of `c` is `Category`.

```Object.entries(category).map([s: string, c: Category] ...```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJB5rW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If all your after is a pure type for `Category`,  then what @jcalz has shown looks good.  But please note you will get type for `categories.cloth.title`, but you wont get code completion for `categories.cloth` that shows `accessories`, and in fact doing `categories.cloth.oops.title` will also be totally valid.

Comment: Extending @jcalz idea, this seems to work -> https://tsplay.dev/m3KXLm

Comment: @jcalz's solution is cool, but it's not completely type-safe

Comment: "not completely type-safe" in what way?  The type `Record<string, T>` is not completely type safe but you're the one who used that type; if you want `Record<string, T | undefined>` or something generic where the keys are known, then you should [edit] the question to demonstrate it.  I'd be happy to write up an answer, or disengage if someone else wants to do it, but please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: @Keith inside second `for of` statement `c` is not a `Category`

Comment: @jcalz What I mean is that the `categories.oops.title` expression in my version of the code will throw an error. Your code solves my problem, but creates another one for me. P.S. I apologize if my goal is not completely clear

Comment: Yes, your code is dynamic,  `Category` is a fixed type, it won't update via code.  Mouse over category and you will see the type `const category: (Category & Record<"dishes", Category>) | (Category & Record<"accessories", Category>)` there is no overlap here, because of this you can use a typeguard,  `if (c instanceof Category) console.log(s, c)`

Comment: `Object.entries()` has issues. If you use it on something with an index signature like `Record<string, Category>`, you'll get `Category`, but on a more specific type like `{dishes: Category}` you get `any`, and you'll need to work around that like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055863/2887218) shows. If you're *not* using `Object.entries()` and just indexing into it manually like `categories.cloth.oops`, then you want `{dishes: Category}` and not `Record<string, Category>`. Can we tighten up the scope here to be just something specific and not all possible uses of `categories`?

Comment: See prev comment.  From an outside perspective, "your code solves my problem, but creates another one for me" is indistinguishable from "I hit another problem after you solved mine so I'm expanding the scope of the question", and the latter tends to devolve into a one-on-one tech support session instead of a FAQ for future readers. If there's some vital use case you need to support, please [edit] the question to show it; otherwise you might want to just ask a new question later which focuses on the followup problem.  I'll disengage now until such time as I see a clarifying [edit]. Good luck!