# How do you define a TypeScript interface with a Key String index but known keys with specific types?

Tags: typescript

How do you define a TypeScript interface with a Key String index but known keys with specific types, so that you can reference the key in a map?

Example Interface (This doesn't work)

```
interface column {
  label?: string;
  width: string;
}

export interface IColumns {
  [key: string]: {
    title: column;
    objectID?: number;
    url?: column;
    author: column;
    comments: column;
    points: column;
    archive: column;
  };
}
```

This is being used like so,

```
const COLUMNS : IColumns = {
  title: {
    label: "Title",
    width: "40%",
  },
  author: {
    label: "Author",
    width: "30%",
  },
  comments: {
    label: "Comments",
    width: "10%",
  },
  points: {
    label: "Points",
    width: "10%",
  },
  archive: {
    width: "10%",
  },
};
```

This is where I map over the converted object and what to reference the key.

```
const Stories: React.FC<{ stories: IStory[] }> = ({ stories }) => (
  <div className="stories">
    <div className="stories-header">
      {Object.keys(COLUMNS).map((key) => (
        <span key={key} style={{ width: COLUMNS[key].width }}>
          {COLUMNS[key].label}
        </span>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean something like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/39281228/863110?

Comment: I saw that before posting my question, It addresses unknown keys with known key child properties but I have known keys and known child properties that I need to reference with a string key. Perhaps my issue is not in the defining of the type but in the mapping of the array.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the issue in your code? Bad autocompletion? A transpilation error?

Comment: No auto completion if I use { [key: string]: column } or Record<String, column>. The key is a generic string so .map works but I have no auto completion of that key only its properties. If I define it without indicating the key is a string I get typescript errors on the .map as i'm using columns[key] to create the column headers.

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://cutt.ly/Bi7boMw). Or you can use `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` so you wouldn't have to cast the value. Just like this: `{Object.entries(COLUMNS).map(([key, value]) => (
  <span key={key} style={{ width: value.width }}>
    {value.label}
  </span>
))}`

Comment: I was able to get the https://cutt.ly/Bi7boMw example working for me. If you post it as the answer ill mark it as complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare a type for the possible keys

```
type Prop = 'title' | 'author' | 'comments' | 'points' | 'archive';
```

Then the interface will use that type as computed key using the [`in`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) keyword

```
type IColumns = {[key in Prop]: column}
```

Now you can use that interface

```
const COLUMNS : IColumns = {
  title: {
    label: "Title",
    width: "40%",
  },
  author: {
    label: "Author",
    width: "30%",
  },
  comments: {
    label: "Comments",
    width: "10%",
  },
  points: {
    label: "Points",
    width: "10%",
  },
  archive: {
    width: "10%",
  },
};
```

About the map, you have 2 options:

1. Use `Object.keys` but case the key into `Prop`

```
(Object.keys(COLUMNS) as Array<Prop>).forEach(key => ...)
```

2. Use `Object.entries` so the `value` will be already `Prop`

```
Object.entries(COLUMNS).map(([key, value /* :Prop */])
```

[playground](https://www.staging-typescript.org/play?target=6&module=5#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezFAvFA5MAlsANhdKAHwwEMBXYACwTkJPQGMEBbFiAO2AGd6MwEWLr2Jk4jKlgBuBANwAoeUOAQ4AM1KNozXORYcoAb3lQouUgCMIuAPwAuKN2BwhAcwWmA7lgAm1B04uHO7yAL6KoJBQAJIAwgi6+tyoRgDaANYQIFBCsIhgALoOOnoc4fLMHE5QsQDyADIAqgCyAHIAylAOcQmlyWjGpth4EA6DpmaW1g4ARAAqOPgzADQmE95+VLMALAAMAKQra6GrphTUtGNrpuZWuLMAgpQ0cEcTUBv+UDMAzAdvUBOa2YbE4PCu71u02+8VBwgBXl8XxmAEZ-qdARiBMpuBCJlD7t8YIJ4RjEZtZmjDhigWdxJIZHjyciqQCgaEFPIABS1CwAKwgjGAADpMiBuFy6k02u0AJRQUjJB5wOCkEAAHngSAAfLLhWpaABRTRULlcsUOLVgeUobVGYEIKrAKBSUi6aBoKUtDoZLIFBShWWyIA)