# Why does annotating this object with a Record type remove Intellisense?

Tags: typescript, record, code-completion, strong-typing

I am creating a data-file that looks like this:

```
interface ISprite {
  textureName: string,
  frame: Frame,
  origin: Vec2,
  zIndex?: number
}

export let sprites: Record<string, ISprite> = {
  monster: {
    textureName: "monster",
    frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 41),
    origin: new Vec2(16, 28),
    zIndex: -1
  },
  player: {
    textureName: "player",
    frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 32),
    origin: new Vec2(15, 32)
  }
};
```

If I then try to import this data file from another file like so:

```
import { sprites } from "../data/sprites";
```

And then try to access a property like this:

```
let player = sprites.player;
```

Then I don't get Intellisense (code completion) when I type `sprites.`

I noticed, however, that if I remove the `Record<string, ISprite>` annotation from the `sprites` variable declaration that I *do* get intellisense.

However, I believe I require this annotation, because one of my functions only takes `ISprite` types, and I don't want to instead make it take an `any`.

Is it possible to maintain the strong typing while also having code completion?

Comment: Try `sprites: {[k: string]: ISprite}`

Comment: @EmanuelVintilă Same problem =(

Comment: because in `Record<string, ISprite>`, the `string` can be any keys. If you want intellisense you need to annotate the keys with union like `'monster' | 'player'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does that because `Record<string, ISprite>` can have **any** string as a key. The UI can't hint every string.

You can give the UI further information to make it show `monster` and `player` for auto-completion by using an intersection between a type with those named properties and `Record<string, ISprite>` (but keep reading, you may not need to):

```typescript
export let sprites: {monster: ISprite, player: ISprite} & Record<string, ISprite> = {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  monster: {
    textureName: "monster",
    frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 41),
    origin: new Vec2(16, 28),
    zIndex: -1
  },
  player: {
    textureName: "player",
    frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 32),
    origin: new Vec2(15, 32)
  }
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUAOViWQbwChllIAPMAVyggDk4BbCALmQGcwcQBzAGkID0AkjCiMWyAGJim-ISQD2ObqFYA1CAgBM-EgC9UIACYQyAflYhKDAEbRCAX0KFTmJWGQAbCB7bZcEGys+AwKIBzQrBj+kLzImJ5wAJ6RaFg4kA7IAGTIAEqaSkYAPBxcfGkxEAB8yAC8BMTIoeGQUMFNJORUNPRMrABELRFQA3LyJMii4pYQAO5SMhAAFAAMcevIAMw6yAAsAIwAlOOTyErAKiCzCxraywcAbHFaABwnncgGxqasALQHJoOXTxRIpdqNM7dah0GbIAYJZLQMaCYSTab9ZAgeaLcRrDZxHaErQfCaKZSqLE4u5aB4AVmJRyBjgA3M55H4MoEAHTIYp1AXIAAWoDAbGQAANhm0Jcg4MZJYjwbKhdAIEA)

**However**:

> I believe I require this annotation, because one of my functions only takes ISprite types.

That's fine. Without any type annotation at all, the values your object has on its `monster` and `player` properties are compatible with `ISprite`, so you can pass them to a function expecting `ISprite`. TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on shapes of objects), not *nominal* (based on names of types), so it's happy to accept any object as an `ISprite` as long as it has all the necessary properties with compatible types. This works just fine, for instance:

```typescript
export let sprites = {
    monster: {
      textureName: "monster",
      frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 41),
      origin: new Vec2(16, 28),
      zIndex: -1
    },
    player: {
        textureName: "player",
        frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 32),
        origin: new Vec2(15, 32)
    }
};

function example(sprite: ISprite) {
    console.log(sprite);
}

example(sprites.monster); // <=== Perfectly happy
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=50#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUAOViWQbwChkTlIAPMAVyggDk4BbCALmQGcwcQBzAGkIB6QaWQwoTVsgBiE5gOGiA9jh6g2ANQgIATANEAvVCAAmEcgH42IKowBG0QgF9Chc5hVhkAGwhf22LgQ7MgAvATEpIxKIJzQbESiJBTUtAzMbABE0bGQUJkKIkniktYQAO4ychAAFAAMfMgNyADMesgALACMAJSFScgqwGogZZVaujVdAGyNOgAcfZGGxmbkbAC0XcvITvqkmN5wAJ7xEQPJ5qn0pciZhyfQBUJFAyUZyCAVVZL1jc1tRptJaKC5DEZjZATHRTACsQJ0PR2LicAG5XDAqCAEGBgDFkOYmIdagEcJA2BhApAeudSAgYuwlL4AHTeJQ8GqkoI9dEuNzkIm+TlU4LMnJxKA85CKAA8oXlyAACtAYNowN5jsgABZwTCYY5AA)

If you want the type name, or hinting for the members of `ISprite` as you're writing futher entries in `sprites`, you could give yourself a function:

```typescript
makeSprite(sprite: ISprite) {
    return sprite;
}
```

It looks like a do-nothing, and it is — at runtime. (Don't worry, it's not expensive). But at authoring time, it lets you do this:

```typescript
export let sprites = {
    monster: makeSprite({
      textureName: "monster",
      frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 41),
      origin: new Vec2(16, 28),
      zIndex: -1
    }),
    player: makeSprite({
        textureName: "player",
        frame: new Frame(0, 0, 32, 32),
        origin: new Vec2(15, 32)
    })
};
```

As you're adding entries, you'll be prompted with the property names from `ISprite` while you're writing the sprite argument for `makeSprite`.

Comment: Unfortunately this object will soon have hundreds of properties so I don't think I can reasonably keep that up. I guess I'll just have to remove the type-annotation and make the function take an `any` instead.. oh well..

Comment: Oh wait, actually, I think I have an idea for a potential work-around.. I'll play around with it for a bit and see if it works

Comment: @RyanPeschel - Heh, I was updating the answer as you posted your comments. See the updated answer, there's no reason to make your function accept `any` instead of `ISprite`.

Comment: @RyanPeschel - I just updated further based on your comment you'll be adding a lot more of these. :-D

Comment: Oh, perfect! Yeah, I think that's a better solution than what I was going to do! I was thinking about doing something like this https://pastebin.com/JVRWLZj5 but I think I like your updated answer better