# How to declare a constant object of string key-values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this object:

```
export const myObj = {
 a: 'someval',
 b: 'someotherval',
 c: 'asdasdasd'
};
```

Which then I use like:

```
const myVar:string = myObj[someOtherVar];
```

What's the proper way of doing this with Typescript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enforcing the type of the indexed members of a Typescript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315131/enforcing-the-type-of-the-indexed-members-of-a-typescript-object)

Comment: The proper way is for `someOtherVar` to be of type `keyof typeof myObj` or `"a" | "b" | "c"`; but you haven't defined/declared `someOtherVar` so I don't know if that works for you.  Please make this code a [mre] and I could maybe answer.

Comment: someOtherVar comes from a request, in the body (this is in an Nextjs formHandler call) so I don't know the type (although I make sure from the UI that it's either a b or c)